# Is there a distance function so that $(\Bbb R,d') $ is compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

let $d(x,y):=|x-y|$ is there a distance function 
$d'$ on $\Bbb R$ s.t. $d'(x,y) \geq d(x,y)$ so that $(\Bbb R, d')$ is compact ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** The condition $d'(x,y)\ge d(x,y)$ means that none of the finite-radius open balls around $0$ according to $d'$ is all of $\mathbb R$. But their *union* is, so together they form an open cover ...